# Add elements to array in specific format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array named $paises:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [life_sciences] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Life Sciences
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 226
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 433
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 816
                        )


                )
            [telecom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Telecom
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 10
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 20
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 30
                        )


                )
        )
)
```

I need transform in another array with json format exactly like this:

```
{
    "dataset": [
        {
          "seriesname": "Life Sciences",
          "data": [{"value": "226"}, {"value": "433"}, {"value": "816"}]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Telecom",
          "data": [{"value": "10"}, {"value": "20"}, {"value": "30"}]
        },
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

What i'm doing returns a wrong array format:

```
$chart = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($paises); $i++) {

        // here i get the value from index 0
        $chart["dataset"][]['seriesname'] = $paises[$i]['life_sciences'][0]['value'];

        // Here i remove the index 0 and reaorder the array indexes
        unset($paises[$i]['life_sciences'][0]);
        array_splice($paises[$i]['life_sciences'], 1, 1);

        // Here i get all values
        $chart["dataset"][]['data'] = $paises[$i]['life_sciences'];

}
```

Result:

```
{
    "dataset": [
        {
            "seriesname":"Life Sciences"
        },
        {
            "data":[{"value":"226"},{"value":"816"},{"value":"1098"}]
        },
        {
            "seriesname":"Telecom"
        },
        {
            "data":[{"value":"10"},{"value":"20"},{"value":"30"}]
        },
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

Note that the "seriesname" is separated of "data":

```
{ "seriesname":"Life Sciences" }, { "data":[{"value":"226"},...] }
```

But what i need is:

```
{ "seriesname":"Life Sciences" , "data":[{"value":"226"},...] }
```

How can i do this in correct way?

########## EDIT 1

I used:

```
$chart = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($paises); $i++) {

        $chart["dataset"][$i]['seriesname'] = $paises[$i]['life_sciences'][0]['value'];
        $chart["dataset"][$i]['data'] = $paises[$i]['life_sciences'];

        $chart["dataset"][$i]['seriesname'] = $paises[$i]['telecom'][0]['value'];
        $chart["dataset"][$i]['data'] = $paises[$i]['telecom'];

}
```

But returns only the "telecom" elements, ignoring the "life_sciences"

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` operator creates a new array element every time you use it. So when you do this:

```
$chart["dataset"][]['seriesname'] = $paises[$i]['life_sciences'][0]['value'];
```

You're appending a new element, and when you do this:

```
$chart["dataset"][]['data'] = $paises[$i]['life_sciences'];
```

You're appending another new element. You can either add them both at the same:

```
$char["dataset"][] = [
    "seriesname" => ...
    "data" => ...
];
```

Or explicitly specify your new index:

```
$chart["dataset"][$i]['seriesname'] = ...
$chart["dataset"][$i]['data'] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but did not work for me, i edited the question with the new issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this for reformatting the array.

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "dataset": [
        {
          "seriesname": "Life Sciences",
          "data": [{"value": "226"}, {"value": "433"}, {"value": "816"}]
        }
    ]
}';

$data = json_decode($json)->dataset;

foreach ($data as $series) {
    $tempArr = Array();
    foreach ($series->data as $value) {
        array_push($tempArr, $value);
    }
    $series->data = $tempArr;
}

print_r($data);


?>
```

To access your data:

```
$data->data
```

Or speries name:

```
$data->seriesname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chart["dataset"][] = array(
    "seriesname" => $paises[$i]['life_sciences'][0]['value'],
    "data" => array_slice($paises[$i]['life_sciences'], 1)
);
```

I think this would be appropriate for cycle body

EDIT 1

After your edition I think about applying something like that

```
$k = array_keys($paises[0]); // get array of keys names
for ($i=0; $i < count($k); $i++) { // iterate key names
    $chart["dataset"][] = array(
        "seriesname" => $paises[0][$k[$i]][0]['value'],
        "data" => array_slice($paises[0][$k[$i]], 1) // array without first element
    );
}
```

Play with snippet to form your solution.

Add one more outside loop to iterate `$paises` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to take the first element of an array (and remove it from the array):

```
function transformPaisesArray(array $paises): array
{
    $transformedPaisesArray = [];

    foreach ($paises[0] as $series) {

        // Take the first element from the array.
        $name = array_shift($series)['value'];
        // Add this first element and the rest as a new record to the target array.
        $transformedPaisesArray[] = [
            'seriesname' => $name,
            'data' => $series
        ];
    }

    // Wrap everything into the dataset field.
    return ['dataset' => $transformedPaisesArray];
}
```